# D3 js with angular 2 popup on clicking the arc of pie

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

```
 public drawPie() {
 let g = this.svg.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(this.pie(this.Stats))
                      .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");
g.append("path").attr("d", this.arc)
                 .on("click",function(event){ console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
                     alert("hello");
                  var person = {
                  fullName: function() {
                    alert("hai");
                   // I want popup code here on click event.                                               
                  }
              }

              person.fullName();
                  ;})

                .style("fill", (d: any) => this.color(d.data.key) );
g.append("text").attr("transform", (d: any) => "translate(" + this.labelArc.centroid(d) + ")")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text((d: any) => d.data.key+": "+d.value);
 }
```

On clicking the arc of pie chart one popup should come and I want to display some data regarding that arc.I am not getting popup. can anyone give me suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need to make a connection between view layer of Angular and the place of code which corresponding to showing the popup.

So, place a popup inside of your HTML, and hide it by default with the some `*ngIf="showPopup"` statement. After, you will need to make two things inside the block which should trigger the call of the popup:

1. Using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator get the element from your view, and set right **X, Y** positions for this element, so it will be placed exactly close to the place it was clicked.
2. Set `showPopup` property to the `true` value, so it will appear.

Let me know about your progress on this one. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
  .on("click",function(event){ console.log(JSON.stringify(event))

                 this.parameter_name=event.data.key;
                 console.log("the clicked paramter name is"+ this.parameter_name);
                 var person = {
                  fullName: function() {
                    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");  

                    newDiv.innerHTML +='<div id="popup" style=" position: absolute;width: 900px ;z-index: 999;display: none;top:150px;margin-left: 350px;margin-right:500px;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px #aaa;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;">'+
                    '<div class="popup_body table-responsive" style="  height: 500px; margin-bottom:10px; ">Recon Report'+                                  
                    '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"><thead class="thead-inverse"><tr>'+
                         '<th>#</th>'+
                         '<th>First Name</th>'+
                         '<th>Last Name</th>'+
                         '<th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th><th>Username</th></tr></thead>'+
                         '<tbody><tr *ngFor="let employee of allEmployees">'+
                         '<td>abc</td>'+
                         '<td>abc</td>'+
                         '<td>abc</td></tr>'+



                    '</tbody></table></div>'+
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:5px"  onClick="(function(){ var el = document.getElementById(\'popup\'); el.style.display = \'none\'; document.body.style.background = \'white\';})();">close</button>'+
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:5px" onClick="(download_csv())">Download CSV</button></div>
                    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("main_container"); 
                    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

                    // open popup onClick
                    openPopup();

                  }

              }
```

I have created popup as shown in the code. The popup is coming but on click event I need to call 
this._myserviceService.reconSrcData(this.recon_name,this.recon_startdate).subscribe(data1 =>{
 console.log("the return pie srccccc data is"+ JSON.stringify(data1));
});

inorder to display the data by collecting through ajax call from spring mvc. But when I placed the code in click event it was showing error like "Cannot read property 'reconSrcData' of undefined"

Comment: Even for download csv button I wrote function and assigned to button on click, but it was showing same error like undefined.         
 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:5px" onClick="download_csv();">Download CSV</button> 
 
 function download_csv() {
   
}